# How do I UPDATE a value in a DB and add another value to it

Tags: php, sql, sum

What I wish to do is to update the value stored in a db to the same value + another value.

Example:

```
$points=$_POST['points'];


$ptsupdt = "UPDATE kids SET points = points + '$points' WHERE name='$name'";
```

Currently when I run this statement, it adds double the value stored in $points.

Example: if $points=5 the updated value will be the original value + 10.

Comment: Why you don't use a trigger?

Comment: The code example appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Prepared statements with bind placeholders are *not that hard*. Really.

Comment: Can you point me to an explanation of anti- SQL injection techniques? I started learning as I am writing this application and wasn't yet to a point where I wanted to focus on that. Though after all the progress I made tonight, I am now. Any links are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't quote $points!

$ptsupdt = "UPDATE kids SET points = points + $points WHERE name = '$name'";

Comment: I wasn't to sure how much that mattered. I had been playing with those quotes on the values because it was doubling the result at the end. That was because I had it running twice though not from the quotes. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was actually running the statement twice during testing and didn't notice until after I posted.

`"UPDATE kids SET points = points + '$points' WHERE name='$name'"` worked perfectly.